# Can I use the existing socket connection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to deliver a message received from elsewhere to a number of specific IP.
A number of specific IP socket connection status is connected.

Can I send a message to find the number of connections currently linked to the IP?

Now brought the connection status connection id.

```
List<String> openConnectionIds = plainServerFactory.getOpenConnectionIds();
```

Is there a way to send messages by using an existing connection?

Or, if I am forced to change the information in the headers can I use an existing connection?

Comment: You can write to any socket you want if there is an established connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard component to send (`TcpSendingMessageHandler`) then you have to set the `ip_connectionId` header for each message; that's how he finds the socket to send to.

If you implement your own `TcpSender` instead, you can send messages to any arbitrary connection (`TcpConnection.send()`) and you don't need to set the header.

You can register your sender with the connection factory (`registerSender()`) so it gives you information about new (and dead) connections, avoiding the need to get the current list.

Comment: I am using ( TcpSendingMessageHandler ).
How do I handle method through the channel comes to the only payload message comes in, the header is modified?

Comment: I don't understand your comment; as I said, you need to send a different message to each socket or implement your own sender.